# sort 2 dictionaries linq c#

Tags: c#, dictionary, nested, sql-order-by

I have 2 nested dictionaries and I want to sort it with 2 criteria. First to orderby by Value.Count and then to order inside dictionary by Value(decimal). I fail with the second sort, because b.Value.Values get Collection which is not sortable. How can solve it ?

```
string path = @"D:\";
        string saveReportPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
    Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, long>> folderContent = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, long>>();

    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path);

    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        string key = Regex.Match(file, @"\.[a-z\d]+$").Value;
        if (!folderContent.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            folderContent.Add(key, new Dictionary<string, long>());
        }
        FileInfo currentFileInfo = new FileInfo(file);
        folderContent[key].Add(currentFileInfo.Name, currentFileInfo.Length);
    }
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, decimal>> folderContent =
   new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, decimal>>();

var orderedDict = folderContent
    .OrderByDescending(a => a.Value.Count)
    .ThenBy(b => b.Value.Values);
```

Simple input

```
D:\
```

Output

```
    .jpg
--FileName.jpg - 1237128kb
--FileName.jpg - 12371282323kb
--FileName.jpg - 1237122323232238kb
.zip
Class.cs - 123kb
and so on..........
```

Comment: Firstly, do you understand that you're not going to end up with a sorted *dictionary*? You can end up with an ordered sequence of key/value pairs - is that okay for you? Secondly, it's not really clear what you mean by "and then to order inside dictionary by value". Do you mean you're trying to reorder the existing "inner" dictionaries, or you're trying to order the outer key/value pairs based on the values within the "inner" dictionaries? A short but complete example including sample input and expected output would make this *much* clearer.

Comment: I am trying to order the outer key/value pairs based on the values within the "inner" dictionaries. Input is a folder path( example D:\). 

Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, decimal>>
string holds all files extensions
Dictionary<string, decimal>
string holds file name
and decimal holds file size

I want order first by extensions and then by size

Comment: Again, so much simpler if you'd edit the question to show sample input/output...

Comment: var orderInnerDict = folderContent.Values.Select(a => a.Values).OrderBy(x => x); 

Am I on a right way?

Comment: How can I tell when you still haven't given us a useful example? (You've suggested an input of a single string, which isn't a dictionary...) I don't know how many other ways I can explain how you should improve your question...

Answer (score 0):

But the second dictionary has multiple values.  You could use sort on first or last item in the values or min/max values or even the sum.

```
var orderedDict = folderContent
.OrderByDescending(a => a.Value.Count)
.ThenBy(b => b.Value.Values.Sum());
```

Comment: .Sum() will gets me a sum from currentValue to lastValue and sort them.